# Distribute and Edit Objects along Polygon

Tags: mirror

I would like to create an object. Multiply it along the edges of a polygon (e.g. pentagon) and then by editing the original object, modify all the duplicated instances. Like a Mirror modifier but not along x/y/z but polygon axis. How is this possible ? Here an image of what I am looking for. The spheres are duplicated along the edges of the pentagon.

Thank you

[image: Example]

Comment: Use either [particle system](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/974/how-can-i-make-a-number-of-objects-sit-snugly-on-an-irregular-surface) or [dupliframes](https://www.blender.org/manual/editors/3dview/transform/duplication/dupliframes.html). Also related - http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/44353/how-to-add-multiple-meshes-on-the-locations-of-the-vertices-of-for-example-a-s

Comment: the link for dupliframes is now https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/3dview/object/properties/duplication/dupliframes.html?highlight=dupliframes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dupliverts should do exactly what you want.

I could spend ages explaining it here, but the [manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.79/editors/3dview/object/properties/duplication/dupliverts.html) does it better :)

You'll need to turn orientation on to get things facing in different directions.

Edit: But do follow the link in Mr Zak's comment, it contains many further examples and an entire alternative method.  Not sure why it wasn't an answer too.