# Vertex count number display

Tags: edit-mode, vertices, shortcut, properties

Is there any way to show the number of selected vertices in Edit Mode?

Answer (score 57):

In 2.9 version of Blender, you can also have the stats in the 3D viewport, using an option in the overlays:

[image]

Answer (score 29):

Here's a 2.8+ answer with some visual reference and additional info.

**1.** First, make sure **Window** > **Show Status Bar** is enabled

[image]

**2.** Next, to see the stats for selected geometry (Verts|Faces|Tris|Objects), **Right Click** on the Status Bar itself and enable **Scene Statistics**

[image: Blender 2.8 and 2.9 - Show Status Bar Scene Statistics]

These settings can also be accessed through **Preferences** > **Interface** > **Editors** > **Status Bar** (and here a contextual Video Memory option is listed as well).

[image]

Comment: This should be an accepted answer.

Answer (score 11):

Switch to edit mode, and the selected vertices will be shown as below:

[image]

As shown there are 4 selected vertices out of 8 vertices in the mesh

Comment: Is there a way to show the vertex number of the selected vertex? For example the rightest vertex is the i-th vertex.