# Blender 3 - Vertex count number display

Tags: 3d-view, interface

How can I show the vertex count for the selected object. The answers I found are for blender 2.X, but are not working for blender v3.

Comment: see the answer here, it is still the same: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/72171/vertex-count-number-display

Comment: Thank you, somehow I clicked on the wrong arrow. Now I found it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somehow I missed it at first.

This is how it works, it is still like in blender 2

Credits to @moonboots.

[image]