# Point features to 3D models with same scale of object

Tags: modeling, transforms

Object Link Data Approach: as suggested in this given link: [Is there any way to replace an object?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/65128/is-there-any-way-to-replace-an-object?newreg=e87a17cbbe624ddcb395d0c96552c923)
I have uploaded my screen shot of my workspace.
[image]

1. IMPORTED SHAPEFILE- using BlenderGIS Addon:- ***yellow*** encircled objects are those **POINTS** of pole locations.
2. IMPORTED COLLADA MODEL- ***Red*** encircled is the **3D collada** model. I need to replace those points with pole.

I hope it is clear now. Pardon my language. I am ready to share the data if required.

- Scales of both objects are different. even sources are different. There are so many such point features in this SHAPEFILE data (110 points needed to be replaced with POLE).
- After doing that, a giant object is displayed as result.

Thanks for cooperating.

Comment: Sorry, it's not quite clear to me what you exactly are you talking about. Could you provide some context? The words "point" and "features" make me think about camera tracking, but you tagged modeling. What are the "transmission poles"?

Comment: I imported shapefile containing locations of transmission poles. then I imported one  transmission pole 3D collada model with required height.      I need to replace that points with the 3D collada model. itried it with "make link with object data", but the size of 3D models are too big. I hope things are clear now.  So I want to replace points with 3D object of required size(here 5meter).

Comment: So you imported two models and their scales don't match? Should they? Do they come form the same source? Objects can be scaled in Blender, what's exactly not working? How are you planning to "replace points with 3D model"? Using a particle system? Dupliverts? Manually? It's hard to help you without further information, please [edit](https://blender.stackexchange.com/posts/105891/edit) your question adding all the info about your situation.

Comment: Thank you, now it's clear. Do the POINTS belong to different objects or are they vertices of the same object? The Link Data appoach works ony if they are all different objects and their origin is properly placed. Did you try the solutions proposed here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/44353/how-to-add-multiple-meshes-on-the-locations-of-the-vertices-of-for-example-a-s ?

Comment: Those all POINTS are of same size. Each point denotes the location of a transmission pole. (i.e., each POINT is different object.)       https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/44353/how-to-add-multiple-meshes-on-the-locations-of-the-vertices-of-for-example-a-s  - This is not am looking for. I would like to create a 3D model of City with Power sSupply system included in the model- like poles, supply lines. So I ahve locations of poles as POINTS. I want o replace those poles as POINTS.

Comment: Could you upload your blendfile or a portion of it to http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/?

Comment: I tried to drag the blend file there. But it id not working.. Anyother option to sent the file?

Comment: I would not recommend any site other than that. What did you mean by "it is not working"? The upload fails? You can't copy/paste the link? Did you check the help page: http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/help/?

Comment: Even if am drag and drop the blend file, that file is not being added/ copied in the specified space.

Comment: Isn't any error/waring appearing? Did you paste the question link in the field?

Comment: there is no warnings/errors. I a =m not able to upload. :-( I am following the same way as mentioned in HELP.

Comment: You can try to contact the runner of the site (mail address can be found at the bottom of the help page) to try to understand what the issue with the uploading is.

Comment: Shall i mail you that in personal if you dont mind. vishnuedakkat93@gmail.com is my mail id. Pls help

Comment: The purpose of using that site is to provide a permanent storage of the file linked to the question that anyone can inspect to help in finding the solution. It's more important you share it with everyone rather than me only: I'm asking questions beacuse the problem is not clear, not because I think I may have a solution. Upload it in another site of this kind if that doesn't work (google drive, dropbox,...) and share the link here. It would be also helpful if you answer all the questions in the comments (e.g. Do the POINTS belong to different objects or are they vertices of the same object?)

Comment: I hope I replied to all the questions. Pardon my language as am poor in communication. Sorry for the trouble. I was not able to understand why that  site was having that issue. I tried in my lap, still faced same issue. I thought of sharing data as that option of uploading was unavailable with me/ my system. i am copying te link here: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1DyBcvPFT8j9AgQpxW4rr6DKvi8SR803D thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Object Link Data substitute the whole mesh, not the vertices

The method you proposed works with the substituction of the Mesh Data, but it requires to have multiple objects to work with (one object for each pole).

Currently, all the points are all binded inside the same mesh data, so they are simple vertices of the same mesh. Points are currently threated as a whole. Look in the outliner that only an object is selected:

[image]

You'll need at least to split each vertex into an individual object and set the origin of each new object on its geometry.

Enter edit mode, select all, press <kbd>P</kbd> and choose "By loose parts". Notice that now the outliner has many object. One for each disconnected vertex.

[image]

Enter object mode without losing the selection and set the origin of all the objects to the geometry.

Now you are ready to Link another Object Data to those object. Before running the operator make sure to apply the scale of your pole object.

[image]

*Note: You'll probably have many advantages in adopting another approach to the task, like for example using the instancing of dupliverts or a particle system which both offer a greater level of interactivity (object is instanced on the fly, you control only the vertices) and avoid splitting the objects in many other objects.*

Comment: Thank you so much.... Really happy with your  response. Thanks..:-)